# How can I override KERNEL_IMAGETYPE variable in machine.conf from my meta layer?

Tags: kernel, yocto, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I would like to build a kernel zImage using [orange-pi-zero.conf](https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi/blob/master/conf/machine/orange-pi-zero.conf)

In orange-pi-zero.conf the uImage is specified:

```
KERNEL_IMAGETYPE = "uImage"
```

How can I override this variable in my meta layer that certain image recipe would use orange-pi-zero.conf but would override KERNEL_IMAGETYPE variable with "zImage" value?

Something like this:

custome-image.bb

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "..."

KERNEL_IMAGETYPE = "zImage"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "${INITRAMFS_FSTYPES}"

COMPATIBLE_MACHINE = "orange-pi-zero"
```

https://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to create a `{MACHINE}-extra.conf` and include it into the `local.conf`

`conf/machine/orange-pi-zero-extra.conf`

```
KERNEL_IMAGETYPE = "zImage"
```

`local.conf`

```
include conf/machine/orange-pi-zero-extra.conf
```